# Can IMG URI be displayed in image.html.twig?

Tags: 8, theming

I want to include [Magnific Popup](https://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup) in my site. The only thing that left to do is display the URL of the image in link wrapping the image field.

I saw that `image.html.twig` modify the image of my articles. So, the override works but when I try to use some variables it just don't work (only atributtes and style_name are allowed).

What can I do if I want to display the URL of `$var['elements']['field_image']['#blazy']['_uri']`(Kint)?

Here is the twig template that I trying to modify:

```
{#
/**
 * @file
 * Theme override of an image.
 *
 * Available variables:
 * - attributes: HTML attributes for the img tag.
 * - style_name: (optional) The name of the image style applied.
 *
 * @see template_preprocess_image()
 */
#}
<a href="#" class="popup-img"><img{{ attributes }} /></a>
```

UPDATE: If I try to use `{{ attributes.src.__toString() }}` as advised in comments of this post, I see this output, not the image `data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg xmlns%3D&#039;http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg&#039; viewBox%3D&#039;0 0 640 257&#039;%2F%3E`

Comment: What about `{{ attributes.src }}`?

Comment: `{{ atributes.src }}` displays `data:image/svg+xml...` not the link that I want.

Comment: `{{ attributes.src.__toString() }}` shows me the relative image URL.

Comment: @renguer0 are you using [svg image](https://www.drupal.org/project/svg_image) module? maybe that changes the output for src.

Comment: No, I'm using blazy with responsive style. With __toString() is still showing this weird output `data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg xmlns%3D&#039;http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg&#039; viewBox%3D&#039;0 0 640 257&#039;%2F%3E`

Comment: This *weird output* looks like inline SVG. So it then as no file URL. But to say for sure please add more details or clarity to your post that lets us reproduce this. Many thanks

Comment: Thanks to you. If I use Kint I see the image (I pasted the path in first post) and I see the field rendered. No weird output from source or dev console.

Comment: Note that if you use just image.html.twig this will affect all image renderings, not just that one field.

Comment: Just affect article images (and that's do the trick). I look into debug theme suggestions in order to edit this thing.

I'm using Blazy on Media entities, so I think that image.html.twig it's the best option to edit. Maybe I can fully edit another template but I really don't know how to do that.